# Count Only if Unique ID Occurs for Multiple Departments?

Tags: tableau-api

Let's say I have some data along the lines of:

```
Department Location  |  Product Sale ID
New York                  ID-1
New York                  ID-1  
New York                  ID-2
New York                  ID-2
California                ID-1
California                ID-1  
California                ID-3
Florida                   ID-3  
Florida                   ID-4
Florida                   ID-5
```

I want to create a new view so that it counts the distinct number of times there is an overlap such the results are:

```
Department Location | Distinct ID Overlap Count
New York              1
California            2
Florida               1
```

In this case, New York has an ID overlap with California on ID-1.  California has an overlap with New York on ID-1 and Florida on ID-3.  Florida, conversely, only has the ID overlap with California on ID-3.

I've looked into doing a LOD calculation along the lines of:

```
{fixed [Department Location]:countd[Product Sale ID]}
```

But I'm not sure how to really to extract the results I want from here.  I'm having trouble thinking of how to approach this logically and am wondering if it is possible or can only be done on the data source side?

Comment: I missed the `tableau` tag, and answered as if you were in an RDMS. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You were on the right track with FIXED. But what we really care about is which Product Sale IDs have multiple locations. You can calculate that with a very straightforward LOD expression:

```
{ FIXED [Product Sale ID] : COUNTD([Department Location]) } > 1
```

With that information now available to us, you just need to count, for each Product Location, the number of distinct Product Sale IDs that occur in multiple locations. Here's one way to do that:

```
COUNTD(
  IIF(
    { FIXED [Product Sale ID] : COUNTD([Department Location]) } > 1, 
    [Product Sale ID], 
    NULL
  )
)
```